# How to make a transparent GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

first i started from [OpenGL test project](https://github.com/zhoumcu/OpenGLTest). Then I added a `CameraView` to it and run the camera like this on `ModelActivity`.

```
private final Runnable mLoadCamera = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        startCamera();
    }
};
```

.......

```
private void startCamera()
{
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(mContext);
    final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    try
    {
        cameraView = new CameraView();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(cameraView);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        Log.d("dddaaaaa", "Another exception");
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("debug", "Another exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(rl != null && surfaceView != null)
        rl.addView(surfaceView);
}
```

then I loaded the 3D object on top of the camera using `GLSurfaceView`.
Now its look like this

[image]

Now I want that purple part to be transparent and see the camera view though it.

I tried it using `GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`. But now it's black instead of being transparent.

[image]

How can i fix this?